# Printer install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, canon

I've been using Ubuntu ever since my 69th birthday which was about 2 weeks ago so I don't know much. Been trying to install printers -- a Canon PIXMA MX340 and an HP Laserjet P1006 in Ubuntu 18.04.1. Working on the Canon today. I downloaded and unpacked gutenprint-5.2.14.tar.bz2. Am now looking at gutenprint-5.2.14 and not knowing what to do next. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What did the README file say or a link to the site for instructions will be helpful!

Comment: Please run `apt search Gutenprint | grep installed` and let me see the output! Add it to your post.

Comment: poppy@Poppy-Alienware-X51-R2:~$ apt search Gutenprint | grep installed

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libgutenprint2/bionic,now 5.2.13-2 amd64 [installed]
printer-driver-gutenprint/bionic,now 5.2.13-2 amd64 [installed]
poppy@Poppy-Alienware-X51-R2:~$

Comment: So you see it's installed by default so you don't need to install from source... Connect your printers and see if they won't be found in CUPS. In your browser go to `localhost:631` then under `CUPS for Administrators` select `Adding Printers and Classes` then `Find New Printers`  and search for them!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much George. My OPERA browser didn't like local host:631 so I switched to Firefox, and then in CUPS I had to first do Add printer and select it from the list.  Now the printer is bouncing merrily along. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome and compliments of the season.